# Deploying Spring MVC webapp

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I've got Spring MVC app with no xml except for pom.xml (full annotation driven). I want to build war and deploy app to tomcat server. I've included maven plugin:

```
<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's my MvcInitializer class:

```
public class MvcInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { MvcConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
}
```

When I build using maven with goal "package" I get following error:

```
Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
```

What do I have to do to get valid war file that can be run in tomcat server?

By the way, I can run my app in Tomcat inside IDE, but I want to deploy it.

Comment: If you have a newer application, I highly recommend using an embedded container with Spring Boot if at all practical.

Comment: Don't you need web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Update**: It's better to add `MvcConfig` as part of your `servlet configs` not `root configs`:

```
public class MvcInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { MvcConfig.class };;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Comment: It successfully generates war file, but after deploying to tomcat views are not showed. Controllers run fine but views don't

Comment: Check your view resolver. Maybe it's a configuration issue

Comment: Ask another question, add your problem details, maybe other guys could help